# 2 column layout, with uneven column length and text wrap

Tags: css, css-float

Is there a way to create a 2 column layout, where one div fluidly expands, after the other ends?

Sort of like in this image:

[image]

Comment: Can't the left div contain the right div?

Comment: You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mdb7S/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3WkPX/2/)?

Take a look of

```
.container {display: inline-block; width: 100%} /* SET CONTAINER */
.col1 {width: 100%;  border: 1px solid red} /* COL1  */
.col1 span {float: right; border: 1px solid red} /* SET FLOAT:RIGHT TO CONTENT OF YOU WANT TO FLOAT */
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a plain color background on container, you may try using box-shadow.

```
#right {
  float:right;
  width:20%;
  width:20vw;
  border:red solid 3px;
  height:50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px white,
    -13px 10px 0 10px blue,
    -13px 13px 0 10px blue 
}
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HKEpo